# Deserialize DeepObject Querystring Keys in Azure Functions / Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, azure-functions, query-string

We are constructing an API with Azure Functions, and the spec calls for DeepObject references in the GET request's querystring.  So, the structure looks like `https://example.com/api/persons?name[first]=Todd`.  The expectation is that **some** of the query keys **may** be DeepObject references, others will be flat.

This is a pattern that apparently Express can handle, but Azure Functions uses an ASP.NET router.  The expectation is that the reference above *should* deserialize into `req.params: { name: { first: "Todd" } }`.  However, instead the output looks like `req.params: { "name[first]": "Todd" }`.

I would really love to not have to regex/search each key, so does anyone know if:

1. There's a config/flag in ASP.NET to support this structure?
2. There's a good pattern in Javascript to deserialize this in some functional -- or at least non-idiosyncratic -- way?

**Note:** Anyone who suggest some use of the `eval()` method will not be selected.  But for playing you will take home a comment with a Nineties reference, because that was the last decade the use of the that method was considered acceptable. :stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I wasn't able to find any way to natively implement this in the ASP.NET router.  Though there is a great deal of suggestions on how to deserialize this structure directly in your ASP.NET controller functions, I am working in Javascript.

What was helpful was the [qs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs), available in NPM, which supports a number of nuances related to this query string structure.

```js
const { query } = req;
// => { "name[first]": "Todd" };

const deserializedQuery = qs.parse(query);
// => { name: { first: "Todd" }
```

Equally helpful to me is that I need a way to restructure my outbound query string in this same format.  Qs works with the `paramsSerializer` attribute in Axios.

```js
const params = { name: { first: "Todd" };
const paramsSerializer = (params) => { return Qs.stringify(params); };
const reqOptions = { params, paramsSerializer };

axios.get("https://example.com/api/persons", reqOptions);
// => GET https://example.com/api/persons?name[first]=Todd
```

Thanks to [@hury-shen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11099213/hury-shen) for a completely workable solution.  It just wasn't turnkey solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, I don't think we can change some configuration to support this structure. What we can do is to implement in code by ourselves.

Here is my function code:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    console.log("======query url is:" + req.url);
    const result = queryStringToJSON(req.url);
    console.log(result);

    context.res = {
        body: "success"
    };
}

function queryStringToJSON(queryUrl) {
    if(queryUrl.indexOf('?') > -1){
      var queryString = queryUrl.split('?')[1];
    }
    var pairs = queryString.split('&');
    var result = {};
    pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
        if (pair.indexOf('[') > -1) {
            var nameObj = {};
            var firstObj = {};
            var nameStr = pair.substring(0, pair.indexOf('['));
            var firstStr = pair.substring(pair.indexOf('[')+1, pair.indexOf(']'));
            firstObj[firstStr] = pair.split('=')[1];
            nameObj[nameStr] = firstObj;
            Object.assign(result, nameObj);
        }else {
            pair = pair.split('=');
            result[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Start the function project, I request it with `http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1?name[first]=Todd&email=test@mail.com`. The result shows:

[image]